# Time series: EWMA pandas forecast

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have searched extensively in Google and here but cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for or at least, some thing I understand. Is it possible to use EWMA in Pandas for forecasting ? For example, if I had daily data of website clicks for 2 months 1st Feb to 31st Mar. and don't see any trend or seasonality in the data, it seems like I should be able to use EWMA to "predict" number of clicks at a later date say on 10th April. In Excel, I can imagine just filling approximately 10 dates or rows after 31st March and computing a moving average where the 5-day EWMA for 10th April will be based on weighted forecasts of prior days. Is there a way I can do this in Python ?

Thanks !

Comment: Anyone  ? Please respond, will be super helpful.

Comment: For a function that produces EWMA estimates for all columns in a pandas dataframe, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665217/coding-the-exponential-moving-average-with-python/45689315#45689315

Answer (score 5):

It's a  one-liner to implement, but you're going to be a little bored by EWMA's predictions of the future (the mean is simply the most recent observation). If you'd like a python package that lets you experiment with EWMA level, trend and seasonality, try my Holt Winters implementation:

https://github.com/welch/seasonal

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/seasonal