# How can I predict next value using moving average/rolling mean

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I just started exploring time-series. I have such df

```
Volume  Year    Month

718394219   2013    01
763723622   2014    01
762225057   2015    01
787479774   2016    01
845614054   2017    01
```

I want to predict the Volume for 2018. The accuracy of the forecast don't need to be high, as I just want to understand the basics.

I made such method, that plots my moving average function along with actual data

```
def plotMovingAverage(series, n):

    """
    series - dataframe with timeseries
    n - rolling window size 

    """

    rolling_mean = series.rolling(window=n).mean()

    #rolling_std =  series.rolling(window=n).std()
    #upper_bond = rolling_mean+1.96*rolling_std
    #lower_bond = rolling_mean-1.96*rolling_std

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
    plt.title("Moving average\n window size = {}".format(n))
    plt.plot(rolling_mean, "g", label="Rolling mean trend")

    #plt.plot(upper_bond, "r--", label="Upper Bond / Lower Bond")
    #plt.plot(lower_bond, "r--")
    plt.plot(series[n:], label="Actual values")
    plt.legend(loc="upper left")
    plt.grid(True)
```

But, I didn't get how can I predict value for the `t+1`

Same question for exponential smoothing

```
def exponential_smoothing(series, alpha):
    result = [series[0]] # first value is same as series
    for n in range(1, len(series)):
        result.append(alpha * series[n] + (1 - alpha) * result[n-1])
    return result
```

Comment: Not sure you're on the right forum. I would have asked that here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ for more practical solutions%)

Comment: Check out the question and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45665217/coding-the-exponential-moving-average-with-python/45689315#45689315

Answer (score 1):

**Prediction:** `pandas` by them self do not have any predictions mechanism implemented. Prediction is a machine learning field use appropriate tools for that or implement your algorithm by hand.
You can use linear models implemented in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) or for special time series prediction model like SARIMAX use [statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) see [how in notebook](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html)

For **window calculations** `pandas` have set of special functions take a look on [EWM](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows) in documentation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a rolling mean will be very useful to you as it will not show you any trends. Say your stock goes up by 10$ every year, your rolling mean will grossly under predict your stock value next year.

I would suggest using a linear extrapolation (of the last 3 units used for instance)

```
import pylab
from numpy import polyfit, poly1d, linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [[718394219,   2013 ,   01],
        [763723622,   2014 ,   01],
        [762225057,   2015 ,   01],
        [787479774,   2016 ,   01],
        [845614054,   2017 ,   01]]

values = [i[0] for i in data]
years = [i[1] for i in data]

plt.plot(years, values)

for i in range(0, len(data)-3):
    # interpolate values
    # you can choose for yourself how many point should be taken into account
    # as well as the degree of interpolation (the last variable mentioned)
    z = polyfit(years[i:i+3],values[i:i+3], 1)
    p = poly1d(z)
    # extrapolate interpolation by 1
    start_year = years[i]
    end_year = years[i+3] + 1
    # plot values 
    x = linspace(start_year, end_year, 10)

    y = p(x)
    plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

you can change this bit to suit your needs:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)-amount_points_used):
    z = polyfit(years[i:i+amount_points_used],
                values[i:i+amount_points_used], 
                degree of interpolation)
```

To be perfectly clear, I have no background in statistics, this is just how I'd go about predicting stuff if the 'accuracy doesn't need to be high'.